# contents() returns empty while contentDocument works

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling with a complex page to select few elements. The main one is a form where I need to read/change some values on the inputs.
So far I'm successfully getting to form using this code:

```
var mainFrame = $(frames[1].document.body).contents().find("#mainFrame1");
```

ok, so I try:

```
$(mainFrame.contents());
```

and it returns empty []... if I try

```
$(mainFrame[0].contents());
```

I get error: mainFrame[0].contents is not a function...

But working with pure JS:

```
mainFrame[0].contentDocument.getElementById("dataForm");
```

works!
I want to keep it into jQuery, and I need to find a few more elements inside this same frame, so I need the mainFrame variable be available for searching all this elements...

Trying to help the answer below find a complete solution I'm posting the console.debug for the mainFrame variable:

```
console.debug(mainFrame);
[frame#mainFrame, prevObject: b.fn.b.init[7], context: frameset#outerFrameSet, selector: "#mainFrame"]
0: frame#mainFrame
    accessKey: ""
    attributes: NamedNodeMap
    baseURI: "https://edited"
    childElementCount: 0
    childNodes: NodeList[0]
    children: HTMLCollection[0]
    classList: DOMTokenList[0]
    className: ""
    clientHeight: 369
    clientLeft: 0
    clientTop: 0
    clientWidth: 1150
    contentDocument: document
                             ->body
                                   ->children (here I can see the form I'm trying to select)
    contentEditable: "inherit"
    contentWindow: Window
    dataset: DOMStringMap
    dir: ""
    draggable: false
    firstChild: null
    firstElementChild: null
    frameBorder: "0"
    hidden: false
    id: "mainFrame"
    innerHTML: ""
    innerText: ""
    isContentEditable: false
    ...
    outerHTML: "<body ..."
    continues...
```

Comment: You can't run `$.contents();` on a DOM node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(mainFrame.contents());` works because `mainFrame` is a jQuery object. jQuery methods can only be applied to jQuery objects.

`$(mainFrame[0].contents());` produces an error because `mainFrame[0]` returns a DOM node from the `mainFrame` jQuery object. Thus, you can't use `$.contents` on it.

To fix this we can rewrite it like so:

```
$(mainFrame[0]).contents();
```

This takes the DOM node and converts it back into a jQuery object, thus allowing us to run `$.contents();` on it. Now obviously this can get messy when trying to use all that as another jQuery object like so: `$($(mainFrame[0]).contents());`. Because of some of this, you have methods like `$.first();` instead of an array returning a DOM node. You also have the CSS `:first-child` selector.

Ultimately, to use `$.contents();` you have to be using a jQuery object against it, not a DOM node which `mainFrame[0]` returns. Your final JavaScript version worked because JS's functions are built to work with DOM nodes, jQuery works with objects though.

Comment: Ok, but the problem still, the solution you gave me, returns an empty object [] while `mainFrame[0].contentDocument` returns the right value...

Comment: `$(mainFrame.contents());` and `$(mainFrame[0]).contents();` returns empty []

Comment: Could I have a link to an example or some code in your question as to what this form looks like. Because your `mainFrame` seems unnecessarily complex.

Comment: The problem is that the code needs login to get reach... The best I can do for this is post here the console.debug for mainFrame

Comment: Could you try posting the snippet in jsFiddle then?

Comment: I'm trying to make this code keep the same problem into a html file, but the website is really complex... I'm losing almost all elements to simulate this on a jsFiddle...

Comment: I posted the console debug on the original question, see if that helps, please.

Comment: One question, is `frames[]` an array of form elements on your page?

Comment: When on console I type `top.frames["` it appears a bunch of stuff as sugestion... Not sure if this answer your question... But, no form elements only, in fact I don't even see the form I'm looking on this list...

Comment: I have good news... I did: `var myDoc = mainFrame[0].contentDocument;` and then: `$(myDoc).find("#mainFrame1");` and I got to the form! Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome. I was actually still debugging and missed this comment. :)